# Performance regression in pandas 1.4.3

Tags: python, pandas

It is much slower now processing a dataframe as compared to 1.4.2 ???

It used to process a 6264 row dataframe at 16.12it/s per second and since I upgraded to 1.4.3 it dropped to 1.1 it/s

Restoring back to 1.4.2 did the trick

This is on a Skylake i7-6700 system (CPU usage also went through the roof)

Comment: could you include how you processed the dataframe?

Comment: I found a report and a fix on this issue


@phofl thanks for redirecting link, I have read everything through and I think this line is cuprit https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py#L8003
when I changed it to
self.loc[:, col] = expressions.where(mask, this, that)
the run time is a lot faster. do you think i should report this as a improvement or a bug?
or this is already in the roadmap?

Comment: https://issuehint.com/issue/pandas-dev/pandas/47392